# How to call a function and give it a string

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Okay, I want to call the function OpenApp() (located in a class called API.vb), but when calling it I want to pass a string to it like that:

```
API.OpenApp("Settings")
```

That's good, but how can I detect that this string has been passed, like so the function knows there's a string?

Comment: did you have the API class code? if no, there should be a documentation for this API to guide you how to pass a string properly to that function?

Comment: API is just the name of the class I made for accessing functions easier. Nothing more.

Comment: (I am making an virtual system overlay)

Comment: If you don't know how to write methods then read a beginner tutorial on writing methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do this then you need to add a definition to the OpenApp() function so the function know what he should do with "settings" strings.

```
Private Sub OpenApp(dial As String)
    Select Case dial
        Case "settings"
            MsgBox("lol")
        Case "something"
            MsgBox("ok")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Marked as best answer.